# Replace de Valor com Python e Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Olá, estou tentando fazer a remoção de um caractere de uma base que extrai de um arquivo TXT, carreguei o arquivo com o pandas porem não consigo remover ele usando o comando replace, abaixo os valores que tenho em uma determinada coluna.

```
0 [23/Mar/2021:00:00:00
1 [23/Mar/2021:00:00:00
2 [23/Mar/2021:00:00:00
3 [23/Mar/2021:00:00:00
4 [23/Mar/2021:00:00:00
```

estou usando o seguindo código para fazer a remoção do "[" com o seguinte comando:

```
y[3]replace("[","")
0 [23/Mar/2021:00:00:00
1 [23/Mar/2021:00:00:00
2 [23/Mar/2021:00:00:00
3 [23/Mar/2021:00:00:00
4 [23/Mar/2021:00:00:00
Name: 3, dtype: object
```

pelo que estou entendendo ele nao esta removendo o caractere porque o tipo do campo esta como objeto, estou precisando fazer isso para outras colunas do meu arquivo porem estou esbarrando nesta conversão, ja tentei o comando abaixo para mudar a coluna para string porem sem sucesso:

```
y[3] = y[3].astype(str)
y[3]
Name: 3, dtype: object
```

Comment: você pode disponibilizar os dados ou fazer um MWE?

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Utiliza assim que dá:

```
text = pd.read_csv('dados.txt', header=None)
text = text.replace('\[', '', regex=True)
```

Comment: segui este também e funcionou ok, muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

Tendo o dataframe abaixo:

```
>>> df
                     txt
0  [23/Mar/2021:00:00:00
1  [23/Mar/2021:00:00:00
2  [23/Mar/2021:00:00:00
3  [23/Mar/2021:00:00:00
```

Basta fazer

```
df['txt'] = df['txt'].str.replace('\[', '')

print(df)
0    23/Mar/2021:00:00:00
1    23/Mar/2021:00:00:00
2    23/Mar/2021:00:00:00
3    23/Mar/2021:00:00:00
Name: txt, dtype: object
```

Acredito que você queira transformar o campo em datetime também, então faça

```
df['data'] = pd.to_datetime(df['txt'], format='%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S')

print(df)

                    txt       data
0  23/Mar/2021:00:00:00 2021-03-23
1  23/Mar/2021:00:00:00 2021-03-23
2  23/Mar/2021:00:00:00 2021-03-23
3  23/Mar/2021:00:00:00 2021-03-23
```

Caso vc somente precise das datas, pode fazer isso de uma vez

```
df['data'] = pd.to_datetime(df['txt'], format='[%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S')

print(df)
                     txt       data
0  [23/Mar/2021:00:00:00 2021-03-23
1  [23/Mar/2021:00:00:00 2021-03-23
2  [23/Mar/2021:00:00:00 2021-03-23
3  [23/Mar/2021:00:00:00 2021-03-23
```

depois jogue a coluna `txt` fora:

```
df.drop("txt", axis=1, inplace=True)
```